# Add Tab Name for opening tab on click of lightning component quick action

Tags: lightning, url, tab, quickaction

I am getting my tab as shown in screenshot below which is a component that gets displayed on clicking a quick action button . currently it is showing asterisk how can i show name on tab.[image]

Comment: please add the minimal required code to reproduce the error?

Answer (score 0):

Use lightning workspace API to rename the tab label for the detailed document you can see the [component library](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:workspaceAPI/documentation).

Here you go the code snippet for same

***Test.Cmp***

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global">

<!--Attributes-->
<aura:attribute name="accFields" type="Account"/>

<!--Component Start-->

<!--Lightning Workspace API-->
<lightning:workspaceAPI aura:id="workspace"/>

<!--Lightning Force Data to get Account record-->
<force:recordData aura:id="accRecordData"
                  layoutType="FULL"
                  recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                  targetFields="{!v.accFields}"
                  recordUpdated="{!c.handleRecordUpdate}"/>
<!--Component End-->
```

***Controller.JS***

```
({
handleRecordUpdate: function(component, event, helper) {
    var accountFields = component.get("v.accFields");
    var workspaceAPI = component.find("workspace");
    workspaceAPI.getFocusedTabInfo().then(function(response) {
        var focusedTabId = response.tabId;
        workspaceAPI.setTabLabel({
            tabId: focusedTabId,
            label: accountFields.Type + ' - ' + accountFields.Name
        });
    })
}
```

})

You can call this method when you need to rename tab. Hope this will help you :)

Comment: i tried what you suggested but it gives error as : Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not locate focused tab..

Comment: when you are calling this method

Comment: in init handler I want to rename the tab as soon as it starts loading , I want instead of loading icon as shown in picture my tab should be renamed.

Comment: can you please your code to see the issue as I can find in your code getFocusedTabInfo is returning undefined